# Difference between "fuggire" "sfuggire" "scappare" "correre"

Tags: word-meaning, word-usage, difference, synonym

Difference between "correre" and "fuggire" are understandable. First is "run" and second more like "run away" as I suppose. But what about "fuggire" and "scappare" in dictionaries they have almost same meaning.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The verbs *fuggire* and *scappare* mean quite the same in several cases. They have different origins: *fuggire* comes directly from Latin *fugio*, whereas *scappare* comes from *excappare*, that is, “to free oneself from a *[cappa](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/cappa1)*”.

The verb is also in French and English (*échapper* and *to escape*).

However, the latter has uses that *fuggire* hasn't. If you look at [the entry in the De Mauro dictionary](https://dizionario.internazionale.it/parola/scappare), several cases for *scappare* cannot be substituted with *fuggire*.

In order to be able to use *fuggire*, the subject should be a person or something thought of as having will: *il tempo fugge* (not *scappa*), but one can't say “mi fugge la pipì”. In other cases *scappare* can be substituted with *sfuggire*: *mi è sfuggito/scappato un errore di stampa*, but not *fuggito*.

When the two verbs are interchangeable, *fuggire* might be perceived as “higher usage” than *scappare*: thinking to my school years, I believe I wouldn't use *scappare* in a “tema” (written paper) if *fuggire* could be used.

Answer (score 2):

It might help to think about the words they are most commonly used with:

- "fuggire/scappare da" + something bad
- "sfuggire/scampare a" + something bad

That's a simplification, of course, you might also see
"fuggire/scappare a + better place".

Essentially, "fuggire and "scappare" imply that you actively did something to get away from something bad whereas "sfuggire" and "scampare" can be used to say you avoided a bad things by luck (even without realizing it).

Examples:

- sfuggire all'arresto = avoid being arrested (usually meant as "getting away")
- scampare al massacro = survive to/avoid a massacre (also by being somewhere else)

"Correre" is quite neutral, you can translate it with "run" practically any time.

Comment: «"Run" is quite neutral»: do you mean “correre”?

Comment: I wouldn't say that sfuggire and scampare involve necessarily some form of luck, even if it is true that sometimes it happens.

Comment: @DaG yes, fixed that. Sfuggire and scampare are usually about getting away from/out of something bad, they imply a bit of luck. I'll add some examples.